# Minimum energy Kardashev scale

Tags: internal-consistency, energy

Other than the original Kardashev scale which ranks civilizations on the amount of energy they control, more specifically the energy from stars, I was intrigued by other more recent scales which take a different approach.

The two which I find the most interesting for my story are the information Kardashev scale and a minimal energy Kardashev scale. The Information scale as stated in its name is based not on energy but the amount of (useful) knowledge a civilization has, which to me is quite similar to the original Kardashev scale, as to gather that amount of information requires energy consumption but the second scale is what I am interested in for this question.

The minimal energy Kardashev scale (I don't know the correct term for it, my apologies) is the opposite of the original scale and states that truly higher civilizations will try to use the least amount of energy possible, until their energy consumption is as close to zero as possible, which sounds
like a neat idea to me but I can't imagine a highly sophisticated and intelligent life-form/civilization running their bodies and technology on close to zero energy without them evolving into some form of static or extremely slow moving life-form, even if they evolve into no longer needing to move, their brains or technology would surely have very slow processing times?

So my question is: Can an intelligent and sophisticated civilization, by human standards and predicted higher levels, exist in this Kardashev scale form of a minimum energy state without breaking the laws of physics?

Comment: Defining "the amount of (useful) knowledge a civilization has" in a quantifiable way is a monumental task. I strongly suspect but cannot prove that this is actually an impossible task. Just defining "useful" much less "knowledge" in a measureable unit is... dubious.

Comment: @PcMan I think this scale is based on bytes of information and the usefulness is mentioned so fans of celebrity gossip are not confused into thinking that is useful knowledge, although it is still social interaction information.

Comment: @nathan-ohaire Using that scale, a raw .BMP image is more advanced than the lossless .PNG compression of the same image. It is a *bad* scale!

Comment: @PcMan I think it is quite a vague scale just to point out that raw power and energy does not make someone intellectually superior and I partially agree that the original scale is slightly broken and pointless and driven to the old world theory of large empires.

Comment: @PcMan and just to point out you are arguing a null point, information is about understanding levels of physics, not compression of data and my question is about the minimal scale and trying to find a loop hole in known physics to give any validity to the theory.

Comment: Then you should not have said quote" I think this scale is based on bytes of information"

Comment: @PcMan Why are you wasting both of our time talking about the scale that the question is not about, is it because you have nothing to say about the scale in the question so you nit pick some time wasting nonsense?

Comment: @PcMan I would have thought with your knowledge of computing you would have mentioned Landau limit and other such minimal energy computing instead of questioning the other scale which my question is not about.

Comment: Why would an advanced civilization try to "use" as little energy as possible?  "Use" being the operative word since energy from the Sun for example is more "caught" than "used".

Comment: "minimal energy Kardashev scale" sounds like it's either in conflict with the laws of thermodynamics, or it is about a civilization of ultra-luddites that want to get rid of every single piece of technology no matter how insignificant, so that the only energy they use is what they can get from nutrients they can find in the wild.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, but it's because you made an assumption that's false

*Truly higher civilizations will try to use the least amount of energy possible, until their energy consumption is as close to zero as possible, which sounds like a neat idea to me but I can't imagine a highly sophisticated and intelligent life-form/civilization **running their bodies** and technology on close to zero energy **without them evolving into some form of static or extremely slow moving life-form.***

- That's a really odd assumption. To my knowledge, the Kardashev scale and its ilk are measurements of technological advancement. NOT measures of evolutionary advancement. Using the assumption you made and applying it to the Kardashev scale would suggest that we've somehow evolved such that our bodies are consuming vast amounts of energy or that we've evolved into all-energy beings. That's not at all what these scales are meant to represent.

Humanity is already advancing along the minimum-energy Kardashev scale that you suggest. Each evolution of electronic hardware must and does consume less energy to perform the same task. This is because the use of energy is not and cannot be perfect — some amount of it is lost as heat. When you use computer CPUs as an example, the more transistors you have, the more heat you generate. Today we have CPUs with [128 cores](https://www.crn.com/news/components-peripherals/ampere-s-new-128-core-altra-cpu-targets-intel-amd-in-the-cloud). Compare that to yesteryear when the same, physical package had only one core. Without advancing along a minimal-energy Kardashev scale, today's processor would create 128X (or more, you'd be surprised how inefficient that process can be) more heat than its predecessor.

If you needed a fan to cool the one-core CPU, without improvements, you'd need full-scale refrigeration to cool the modern 128-core device. Here's my point: ***you don't need that much cooling to cool the modern device.***

That's because along with learning how to pack more transistors onto a slice of silicon, we've also learned how to manufacture those transistors to consume less energy to do their job. Less energy means less excess heat.

*And we haven't broken the laws of physics yet*

I'm an electrical engineer. When I started engineering, we were building sub-micron circuits. At that time (the mid-1980s) the industry *actually thought it was physically impossible to build nanometer geometries.* The molecular size of polysilicon, used to make MOSFET gates, is measured in angstroms (e<sup>-10</sup>) and at the time it was deemed impossible to build a gate smaller than 10 angstroms (100nm).

[Until some fool threatening the very foundation of Heaven did it!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/90_nm_process)

**Don't get caught in the trap of believing that what we know today is all there is to know**

When you say, "break the laws of physics," you can only mean "break the laws that we understand today." Just because we don't know how to do something today doesn't mean it can't be done tomorrow. In fact, what it usually means is that when we understand physics better, then we can do that thing.

That was an ugly way of saying, sure, such a scale makes sense and won't break any laws of physics — but it will without doubt require us to learn more about the laws of physics before we get there.

**So, let's conclude by pointing out a way to understand a minimum-energy Kardashev scale**

One of the reasons the classical Kardashev scale makes so much sense is because it's reflecting, from a point of view, the amount of energy consumed by a society *on a per-person basis.* (Yes, I know that's not how it's measured.)

Now, I have no idea how to conveniently measure this, so I'm going to use some pull-it-out-of-my-hat numbers that have no actual reflection on real life. It's the relationship between the numbers that's important.

- Let's say a caveman 30,000 years ago consumed 1 million btu throughout his life. How is that energy produced? Basically, fire. That's it. (Am I wrong?) We could go into the energy created when he eats, but that doesn't change throughout history. (And that's important, right? Because the scales don't measure how humans change. They measure how humans consume.)
- Now let's say that today the average person consumes 1 billion btu. Here in the U.S., we almost all have cars, light bulbs, computers, phones.... We're burning energy like there's no tomorrow. Energy is burned on our behalf keeping meat cold at the grocery store and repairing roads, etc. Each individual represents a chunk of all the energy produced in the world.
- Now let's say that 1,000 years from now each individual represents 1 trillion btu of produced energy. Space ships are moving goods around that each individual depends on. Vast communication, transportation, and manufacturing networks... and all that produced energy can be represented as a per-person number.

See how the Kardashev scale can be expressed as a per-person consumption number? Now let's look at the minimal-energy scale, which of necessity represents the improved efficiency of doing more and more things.

- That caveman drew on a cave wall with a burnt stick. He did it all his life, but let's suggest that he represented a few ideas with a lot of effort. He created spears to hunt food and broke rocks to cut things. It was a lot of work, despite the productivity enhancements they provided. It's not easy to represent this as a number, but let's assume he burned 1 million btu and processed 10kb of information in his lifetime for a minimal-energy-Kardashev-scale (MEKS) value of 100,000.
- Today, we can do unbelievable things with computers, hydraulics, automation... We may burn 1 billion btu in our lifetimes, but we can process *terabytes* of information. the MEKS value is 1x10<sup>-3</sup>.
- 1,000 years from now we may have 1 trillion btu burned on each individual's behalf, but an exabyte of information processing took place in that lifetime. MEKS = 1x10<sup>-6</sup>.

Can you see how a minimal-energy scale works? *Less energy is being used for each unit of work.* Coming up with a way to measure that improved efficiency is a pain in the tuches, but it can be done. One way we've done it today is using [Moore's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law) to measure the increasing density of electronics on a chip over time. Another way would be to measure power consumption vs. CPU cores.

**One last thing**

It might help to think of the Kardashev scale as infinitely increasing.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$$

The only practical limit is the sum-total of the energy in the universe. *Except that it's actually impossible to reach that point.* There's a limit to the amount of energy that can be used by any civilization without ripping the proverbial hole in the fabric of space-time.  So, in reality...

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = Y<\infty$$

where "Y" is the maximum amount of energy that can be consumed by a single civilization, whatever that is. We can do the same thing with the minimal-energy scale.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$$

Which is impossible. You can't, for example, lift a 10g slug off the floor and consume no energy at all.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = Z>0$$

In other words, The point of the scale is to demonstrate a *progression toward a minimal consumption of energy per-unit-of-work,* whatever that minimum may be.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I knew most of this already FYI this is the paper it is from, the theory is to merge with the environment, that is why why I talked about their bodies and not just their technology https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.13221.pdf

Comment: Maybe I should edit the question with the paper linked so I can get more specific answers? I just didn't want to force feed too much information and I wanted to see how member interpreted a minimal energy situation. On a side note a play on the words as you mentioned is putting less in than you gain so different energy sources could fit the brief.

Comment: I deleted my previous disrespectful comments as I can hardly ask for help and have a bad attitude at the same time :)

Answer (score 2):

> truly higher civilizations will try to use the least amount of energy possible

Energy usage being a non negative number by necessity, it follows that its minimum is necessarily 0. Since a living being has to consume energy to survive, even including in the definition of life non carbon based life forms based on computronium, there cannot be any life with 0 energy consumption.

And based on the examples we have, the more complex a life form is, the more energy it uses: a virus uses way less energy than an amoeba, which uses less energy than an ant, and so on and so on.

Wrapping up, I don't think that the scale as you have defined it makes any sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

#### I think you want minimum energy *per unit of accomplishment*

I think your observation is fair - minimising energy consumption would be a goal as a civilisation advances, however L Dutch is right, measuring this as absolutes runs backwards - the optimal score (0) could be quickest achieved with collective suicide.

Lets consider 4 civilisations:

- A's, have a Dyson Sphere, a population of 1 billion, mostly living in poverty, and are mining a few asteroids.
- B's, have covered their planet in high altitude solar panels, a population of 50 billion living in post-scarcity luxury, are mining their entire solar system, and have sent generation ships to neighbouring systems.
- C's are hunter gatherers.
- D's are current 2020 Earth.

On the Kardashev scale - A's are the "superior civilisation", but any casual observer should give that label to B. They consume less power, and accomplish much more with it.

How do you rank "accomplish more"? This is pretty difficult to state objectively - find the most accomplished society give them an accomplishment ranking of 100, and then set every other civilisation relative to it:

- A : 25
- B : 100
- C : 0.0
- D : 5

Then measure how much power they're consuming, eg divide it by log10 of power consumed in watts.

- A : 25 / 26 = 1.04
- B : 100 / 20 = 5
- C : 0 / 1 = 0
- D : 5 / 12 = 0.5

In this scale higher score is better - but power generation is on the denominator, it's like the inverse of Kardashev scale:

- As you gather more power and waste it, your score goes down.
- As you lower your power consumption and keep your level of activity, your score goes up.

Comment: Collective suicide would only limit their own energy consumption. It would make more sense, accepting that energy is always used regardless of their actions, to limit the expenditure. Like you suggest, put it to the most efficient use possible.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, the Kardashev scale itself is very, uh, brute force in its aesthetic.  Very 20th century materialistic, Soviet Man conquers space kinda thing.  20th Century Man was building big hydroelectric power plants, lighting up big wasteful lightbulbs, driving big gas-guzzling cars, and blowing up big atom bombs. So  their futurists naturally imagined 30th Century Man (yes, man, since they were all sexist back then) as doing basically the same thing, but BIGGER. So more power, bigger, heavier, whatever.

In fact, if we can say one thing for sure from the perspective of that 30th century being, it's that the Kardashev focus on energy scale missed the point entirely. Sure, in the short term (a few centuries) the (post)humans might blob and bloat a bit and build gaudy and wasteful Dyson Swarms and whatnot. But as the 21st century already showed, the more interesting aspects of the universe are always going to be computational. Beyond a certain threshold of intelligence, it's better to be smart than to be strong.

So, we currently have laws about the minimum energy needed for "irreversible" computation, something called the [Landauer minimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle). It depends on temperature, so folks looking at the Fermi Paradox suggested an aestivation hypothesis (all the civs are sleeping and waiting for the "weather" to get better for computation), but this misses the point again.

Think about it. The universe itself is a massive computation. Every blob of what we call "waste heat" performs an unbelievable amount of computation, just to advance the local area to the next instance of plank time. It's in fact likely that most computation happens in empty bits of space, just to maintain metadata like the basic existence and the curvature of spacetime and the dozens of overlapping fields at work. All this stuff we call matter & energy is a light foam on top of a deep ocean of computation. We only see the foam because the ocean is everywhere and looks pretty uniform when you are in the foam and don't know what you're looking for.

So, will a *truly* advanced civilization be content to work with the scraps of foam, or will it delve deeper and embed itself into the deeper pattern? It's a rhetorical question, of course, as any civ worth their salt will go for it (assuming this is even possible, since our current physics say we're stuck w/ the foam bits, but what do we know). From our current perspective, **The total "power" consumption of such an embedded civ will be zero or very close to zero**, since any calculations done by such a civ will be seen as waste heat by us or even as "weird random quantum activity in the vacuum".

Makes you wonder if, a billion years from now, some new, emergent civilization in a far away galaxy will wonder about the whys of the five basic forces: gravity, electromagnetism, the weak, strong and the human force. Or perhaps humanity will be perceivable as a weird kind of symmetry breaking. We're too dumb and primitive to know, which is kinda the point.